# Custom sort before ROW_NUMBER() for paging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following

```
SELECT results.*, coinCat.*, cat.* 
FROM (SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.CoinId) AS RowNumber 
      FROM coins c) AS results
INNER JOIN CoinCategoriesCategories coinCat ON coinCat.CoinId = results.CoinId
INNER JOIN CoinCategories cat ON cat.CategoryId = coinCat.CategoryId
WHERE RowNumber>= @pageNumber * 1 AND RowNumber<@pageNumber *@pageSize
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

The statement must be nested in order to please Dapper (ORM),

Before applying/paging, I would like my results to be sorted by Coins.Rank but not sure where to stick that part so that my query can run properly and paging works happily

Also would this statement be any different between SQL Server vs PostgresSQL as an example?

Comment: How is `Coins.Rank` derived? Is this a column in the table? Is it unique? Part of the key? Also please see [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) because all those `*` references are probably going to make this pretty abysmal as you increase `@pageNumber` (especially if you don't have an index that supports your sorting).

Comment: I am an idiot, instead of ORDER BY c.CoinId i just did ORDER BY c.Rank and that worked

Comment: Ok, let us know how performance goes as the table gets bigger and page number goes up...

Comment: Given the query, will performance be an issue for me if i have less than 5000 records in coins?

Comment: You'll have to let us know. Number of rows is not necessarily an important criteria, but rather the number of pages (which is dictated by a combination of number of rows, width of those rows, fragmentation, suitability of indexes, among other things...).

Comment: Also: the way the query is constructed (and the 1-to-many join between Coins and CoinCategoriesCategories)), the number of rows returned by the query will vary, depending on whether the selected (by the size and offset) rows in Coins are related to 1 or many (or 0) categories.

Answer (score 3):

instead of ORDER BY c.CoinId i just did ORDER BY c.Rank and that worked

```
SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Rank) AS RowNumber FROM coins c
```